# CSS Chrome-only space at top of div

Tags: css, google-chrome, drupal, margin, space

I've been searching all day for a solution but have yet to find one. Safari and firefox display this perfectly but Chrome has a ~100px space at the top of the #content div.

http://co.ably.ca/

See site in chrome and then in ff and safari. I've colored the offending div in green. What could be causing this?

Comment: I've isolated part of the problem, the #block-block-5 div that is floated into my header seems to be causing this, at least in part, if I remove that block, the space disapears... but of course I can't remove that block, as it is an integral part of the site...

Comment: The page looks identical to me in Chrome and Safari. Did you fix the issue?

Comment: I just fixed the issue, a div from the #header was having it's original place in the code reserved by Chrome, even though it was floated. I changed it from a 'float' to a 'position:absolute' to completely remove it from the flow (which float is supposed to do) and the problem is resolved...

Answer (score 1):

If I remove `overflow: auto;` from `h1.title`, the top-green-bar disappears in my screen.

Comment: By remove you mean deselect the checkbox when Inspecting? This changes nothing for me... oh actually this does get rid of it, only on the main page though. I'm probably on the right path here, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The element h1 has the follow attributes:

```
-webkit-margin-before: 0.67em;
-webkit-margin-after: 0.67em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
```

I think this is your problem.